Centrar campo agrupado en localreport
Estoy haciendo un LocalReport con Visual Studio 2010 (C#).
Quiero agrupar los registro por el campo FechaReg y que cada vez que cambie, aparezca solo en un renglón y centrado. Como lo hago?


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
